# What do you call someone who always speaks in gobbledygooks?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, synonyms, vocabulary

What word would you use to describe a person using gobbledygooks even during casual conversations?

[image]

Comment: Aside: like English, gobbledygook is a singular word.

Comment: Answers I like from that question are [**gasbag**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gasbag) and, my favourite, [**blatherskite**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blatherskite).

Comment: @JasonBassford +1 for "blatherskite." :)

Comment: You don't 'speak Englishes'.

Answer (score 0):

From Lexico:

> **[gobbledygook](https://www.lexico.com/definition/gobbledygook)**: Language that is meaningless or is made unintelligible by excessive use of technical terms.

If we go with "language that is made unintelligible by excessive use of technical terms", all we need to do is ask ourselves who makes excessive use of technical terms: **nerds**. From Lexico:

> **[nerd](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nerd)**: A single-minded expert in a technical field.

As far as most people are concerned, **nerds** speak obsessively and incessantly in the gobbledygook of the technical field in which they are expert.

Comment: Except that *nerd* doesn't mean *obsessed with gobbledygook*. A nerd could speak completely normally, but be obsessed with something else entirely. Really, what's required is a word that really does mean *obsessed with gobbledygook* specfically.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for the comment. I didn't say nerds are obsessed with gobbledygook. They are obsessed with their technical field (ref. definition of **nerd** re nerds being *single minded*) and so they speak obsessively and incessantly (ref. definition of **nerd** re nerds being *single minded*) in the language of that field. Their language is unintelligible to anyone not an expert in that field virtue of their excessive use of the technical terms of that field (ref. definition of **gobbledygook** re *unintelligible* and *excessive use of technical terms*).

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't read the question as being about a person *obsessed* with gobbledygook. A person could speak gobbledygook 24/7 without being obsessed with gobbledygook. For example, a person might be obsessed with something else that causes her to speak in what most people would consider gobbledygook (e.g., this person could be a nerd). Or maybe this person is simply an unclear thinker *par excellence* and therefore constantly spouting nonsense. Or maybe this person speaks gobbledygook on purpose as part of an effort to hide their incompetence. Etc.